# Game character not moving

Tags: c#, xna, mono, monogame

I've been trying to write a really simple game with MonoDevelop and MonoGame.
I'm trying to make an enemy character move across the screen in a straight line.

I've written this code to do that so far:

```
//draw enemy on screen
int enemyYPosition = 720;
int enemyXPosition = 1200;

drawEnemyRectangle.Y = enemyYPosition / 2;
drawEnemyRectangle.X = enemyXPosition;

if (enemyXPosition > 0) 
{
    enemyXPosition -= 50;
} 
else 
{
    enemyXPosition = 1200;
}
```

However when I run the game, the enemy appears in the middle right of the screen just fine, but it then won't move.

What have I done wrong?

The rest of my code can be found here: http://pastebin.com/gVEAkMWa

Comment: We need a little bit more of your code I think

Comment: Out of curiousity, do you know that the `enemyXPosition` changes? I'm unfamiliar with C#, but can you put in print statements to show the value of `enemyXPosition` right before the if-check?

Comment: Make sure your initialisation code isn't in the same body as the update code, else it will just revert back to the default values each time (720 / 1200)

Comment: How do you draw it? With GDI+? We need more code... Maybe you should also put that code in other events and invalidate

Comment: I'd  say you should consider using more of an object oriented design. Have an enemy class that includes X and Y variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your initialisation code is separate from the update code.

Your update method look something like:

```
 public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
 {
   //The rest of your update code here

   drawEnemyRectangle.Y = enemyYPosition / 2;
   drawEnemyRectangle.X = enemyXPosition;

   if (enemyXPosition > 0) 
   {
      enemyXPosition -= 50;
   } 
   else 
   {
     enemyXPosition = 1200;
   }
 }
```

Your variables would then be initialised elsewhere, for example:

```
   int enemyYPosition;
   int enemyXPosition;
   public Game1()
   {
     enemyYPosition = 720;
     enemyXPosition = 1200;
   }
```

This is of course a guess as you haven't provided much code.

**Update:** after looking at your full code, it seems to be exactly this problem.

Comment: Thanks, implemented this and it works fine, thanks!

Comment: Try to tidy the rest of your code up a bit. In the draw method for example, make sure you call base.Draw() after your own draw logic. Your update method is also getting pretty big, I'd consider refactoring some of that logic out somewhere else.

Comment: You should also get into the habit of multiplying your movement by game time so that it will work at different frame rates.